# saving two Rails models with accepts_nested_attributes_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models: author and profile.  Author accepts_nested_attributes_for profile.  I can't figure out how to save the profile model (namely the :avatar attribute) through author.

**author.rb**

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile
end
```

**profile.rb**

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader
  belongs_to :author
end
```

**authors_controller.rb**

```
class AuthorsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_author, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @authors = Author.all.order("last_name ASC, first_name ASC")
  end

  def new 
    @author = Author.new
  end

  def create
    @author = Author.new(author_params)

    if @author.save
      AuthorMailer.activate(@author).deliver
      flash[:notice] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :new
    end

  end

  def edit
    @profile = @author.build_profile
  end

  def update 
    if @author.update(author_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Profile has been updated."
      redirect_to @author
    else
      flash[:alert] = "Profile has not been updated."
      render :edit
    end
  end

  private

    def author_params
      params.require(:author).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :avatar)
    end

    def set_author
      @author = Author.find(params[:id])
    end 
end
```

**app/views/authors/edit.html.erb**

```
<div class="center">
  <h1>Edit Author</h1>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-lg-4 center-block">
    <%= simple_form_for(@author, :defaults => { :wrapper_html => {:class => 'form-group'}, :input_html => { :class => 'form-control' } }) do |f| %>
      <%= f.input :first_name %>
      <%= f.input :last_name %>
      <%= f.fields_for [@author, @profile] do |p| %>
        <%= p.file_field :avatar %>
      <% end %>
      <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn small btn-default" %> 
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

This form doesn't save anything to my profile table.

**EDIT1**
updating the permit parameters didn't save anything to the profile table.  But I did notice that adding the following to my authors_controller in the update action saves an incomplete record to the profile table (the avatar field is blank):

**author_controller#update**

```
if @author.update(author_params)
  @profile = @author.build_profile()
  @author.profile = @profile
  flash[:notice] = "Profile has been updated."
  redirect_to @author
else
  flash[:alert] = "Profile has not been updated."
  render :edit
end
```

I tried placing pry inside the update action and my params look like this:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"patch",
 "authenticity_token"=>"EROrMzOejPmMU/wzlnC5iaoTPu4pyBXelHAs3uiPA2U=",
 "author"=>
  {"first_name"=>"Mike",
   "last_name"=>"Glaz",
   "profile"=>
    {"avatar"=>
      #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007feb48127ab0
       @content_type="image/jpeg",
       @headers=
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"author[profile][avatar]\"; filename=\"me_and_lekeziah.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
       @original_filename="me_and_lekeziah.jpg",
       @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20140504-15793-l4uu6l>>}},
 "commit"=>"Submit",
 "action"=>"update",
 "controller"=>"authors",
 "id"=>"3"}
```

so then I tried the following in my update action:

```
@profile = @author.build_profile(params[:author][:profile])
@author.profile = @profile
```

but then I get the following error:

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError in AuthorsController#update
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use "fields_for" for a  association model xxx, your params need to permit :xxx_attributes fields, which's value should be a array include it's attributes, so change your author_params method to something like this:

```
def author_params
  params.require(:author).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, profile_attributes: [:avatar])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should update your params permitted fields as:

```
def author_params
  params.require(:author).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :profile_attributes[:id, :avatar])
end
```

Second, you are mixing Rails form_for helper and Simple_form in your view.

change

```
<%= f.fields_for [@author, @profile] do |p| %>
```

to:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for [@author, @profile] do |p| %>
```