# Rails - Saving two related models through nested forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models one User, and UserProfile. UserProfile belongs to User, and User has one UserProfile. When user signup it is one form collecting all the information and information goes into two different models. I cant seem to achieve this. I used accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_profile on user model. Still only User model gets saved but not the UserProfile
My View:

```html
   <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name, class: 'form-control'%>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.email_field :email, class: 'form-control'%>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password, class: 'form-control'%>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, class: 'form-control'%>
       <h3> Profile Information</h3>
        <%= f.fields_for @user.user_profile do |profile_form| %>
            <%= profile_form.label :age %>
            <%= profile_form.text_field :age, class: 'form-control' %>
            <%= profile_form.label :height %>
            <%= profile_form.text_field :height, class: 'form-control' %>
            <%= profile_form.label :contact %>
            <%= profile_form.text_field :contact, class: 'form-control'%>
            <%= profile_form.label :city %>
            <%= profile_form.text_field :city, class: 'form-control'%>
            <%= profile_form.label :state %>
            <%= profile_form.text_field :state, class: 'form-control'%>
            <%= profile_form.label :batting_style %>
            <%= profile_form.text_field :batting_style, class: 'form-control'%>
            <%= profile_form.label :bowling_style %>
            <%= profile_form.text_field :bowling_style, class: 'form-control'%>
            <%= profile_form.label :favorite_players %>
            <%= profile_form.text_field :fav_players, class: 'form-control'%>
            <%= profile_form.label :favorite_team %>
            <%= profile_form.text_field :fav_team, class: 'form-control'%>

  <% end %>
        <br>
        <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-primary" %>

  <% end %>
```

My Users Controller

```
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @user_profile = @user.build_user_profile
  end

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user_profile = @user.user_profile
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      @user.build_user_profile
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def user_params
     params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, user_profile_attributes: [:age, :contact, :height, :city, :state, :batting_style, :bowling_style, :fav_team, :fav_players])
  end
```

Application Log:

```
Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2015-03-31 14:38:58 -0400
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"tAFZCk9+l0ksbMSZ8OEosQP5VBRfYfvZ3RR5/tkkW3Dr16+h2Xr1m8ITt+zJvigZpaN4lIchFhPrIx81lf6wNA==", "user"=>{"name"=>"Test User", "email"=>"testuser@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "user_profile"=>{"age"=>"29", "height"=>"5 feet 4 inches", "contact"=>"888-888-8888", "city"=>"Philadelphia", "state"=>"PA", "batting_style"=>"Right hand", "bowling_style"=>"Right Arm", "fav_players"=>"Test", "fav_team"=>"Test"}}, "commit"=>"Create my account"}
Unpermitted parameter: user_profile
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('testuser@gmail.com') LIMIT 1
  SQL (1.6ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "email", "password_digest", "created_at", "updated_at", "activation_digest") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["name", "Test User"], ["email", "testuser@gmail.com"], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$LsY8eVTzj0CNGUp1WLiZN.DOLRbU1Qyg8W/dUHDo77YmKH099.oOa"], ["created_at", "2015-03-31 18:38:58.699583"], ["updated_at", "2015-03-31 18:38:58.699583"], ["activation_digest", "$2a$10$y7iCb2vOJzTExisD.vkYzOWxs55W.FiYZ56aGYd028s49i1j9r3su"]]
   (0.8ms)  commit transaction
  UserProfile Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "user_profiles".* FROM "user_profiles" WHERE "user_profiles"."user_id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 120]]
  Rendered user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb within layouts/mailer (0.4ms)
  Rendered user_mailer/account_activation.text.erb within layouts/mailer (0.1ms)
```

Trying Different Ways: Still no luck

```
     def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user_profile = @user.build_user_profile(params[:user][:user_profile])

   if @user.save
      @user.send_activation_email
      flash[:info] = "Please check your email to activate your account."
      redirect_to root_url
   else
      render 'new'
   end
  end
```

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23451272/saving-two-rails-models-with-accepts-nested-attributes-for?rq=1

Comment: Thanks  Sixty4Bit,  and that question did not answer my question....I  am still struggling to get that working